# AADSTS70012: Non-retryable error has occurred

Tags: oauth-2.0, outlook, office365api

https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token

I am trying to hit this url to obtain the access_token, when I obtain the auth code from users consent from browser I am getting the access_token and refresh_token as well, but I when I try to obtain a new access_token using the refresh_token, I get the error

```
{
    "error": "temporarily_unavailable",
    "error_description": "AADSTS70012: Non-retryable error has occurred.\r\nTrace ID: de6cff9d-0ad2-46ac-83b7-ecd086dd1500\r\nCorrelation ID: c0fdbd54-1b22-43a1-be2f-7bee48534abe\r\nTimestamp: 2018-08-18 14:34:28Z",
    "error_codes": [
    70012
    ],
    "timestamp": "2018-08-18 14:34:28Z",
    "trace_id": "de6cff9d-0ad2-46ac-83b7-ecd086dd1500",
    "correlation_id": "c0fdbd54-1b22-43a1-be2f-7bee48534abe"
}
```